# VBA: Why is Range.Find.Execute deselecting text in a Word doc?

Tags: vba, selection, ms-word

Why this VBA code ((initial part of a sub) modifies the visible selection in the Word document? I'm not modifying any selection. As per MSDN description:

> "If you've gotten to the Find object from the Range object, the
>   selection isn't changed when text matching the find criteria is found,
>   but the Range object is redefined.
>   (Taken from: [Find Object (Word)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839118(v=office.15).aspx))

So the following code should just modify the Range, and not affect the selection at all...

> ```
> Sub SelectTarget()
>     Dim MyRange As Range
> ```
>
> > ```
> >     Set MyRange = Selection.Range
> >     With MyRange.Find 'Searches for _AM or _PM  (_ is a space)
> >         .ClearFormatting
> >         .MatchWildcards = True
> >         .Text = " [AP]M"
> >         .Execute
> >     End With
> > ```

This is a screenshot of a doc with some text selected (what I call the visible selection):

[image: Visible text selection right before executing the <code>Range.Find</code> code]

But executing the code step by step with F8 one can see that after the `.Execute` line, the visible selection in the document disappears and the text background remains all white with no selection at all, not even an insertion point.

I have tried entering `Replacement.Clearformatting` and `Replace = ""`lines in the code to try to prevent previous Find/Replace from interfering, but it doesn't change anything whatsoever... 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why it is setting MyRange to the selection rather than the selection's range, but perhaps Word considers those two to be synonymous. Try

```
Set MyRange = Selection.Range.Duplicate
```

so that changes to MyRange don't affect Selection.Range at all.

Comment: Thanks Christina, for some reason I couldn't answer you before; I'll be able to check/comment on what you say in a few days. Yet I'd still would like to understand why does that with the code I made, or at least to know if it is a bug. It seems strange that nobody knows here in all this time as I'm not an VBA expert so it can't be such a hard question...   Thanks anyway!